# How to detect alarm ringing or other apps using speaker?

Tags: android, audio, alarm, speaker

I am developing a music app. I want to detect that other apps using speaker or alarm ringing for play/pause music.

For phone call i use PhoneStateListener. I tryed OnAudioFocusChangeListener for to detect other audios. But didn't work.

I wondering how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem for default alarm application:

```
public static final String ALARM_ALERT_ACTION = "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT";
public static final String ALARM_SNOOZE_ACTION = "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE";
public static final String ALARM_DISMISS_ACTION = "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS";
public static final String ALARM_DONE_ACTION = "com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE";

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (action.equals(ALARM_ALERT_ACTION) || action.equals(ALARM_DISMISS_ACTION) || action.equals(ALARM_SNOOZE_ACTION) || action.equals(ALARM_DONE_ACTION)) 
          {
              // for play/pause mediaplayer
              playPause();
          }
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ALARM_ALERT_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(ALARM_DISMISS_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(ALARM_SNOOZE_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(ALARM_DONE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

Comment: Does not work in Samsung Galaxy S*

Comment: Samsung has a custom alarm clock app, works with the stock one like a charm

Comment: does not work on LG alarm clock and Google's alarm clock. Better to implement a alarm clock yourself than depending on something else.