# How to detect the alarm event?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I´m developing a music application.
When an alarm starts, the streaming of music must stop. 
The problem is **how to detect the alarm event**. The alarm may sound at any time. It is set by the user with the android alarm system.

Comment: set broadcast reciever to listen that event

Comment: This should solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844657/how-to-detect-alarm-ringing-or-other-apps-using-speaker

Comment: ok, I have read the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844657/how-to-detect-alarm-ringing-or-other-apps-using-speaker

Comment: but my app not working. I have created an broadcast receiver, but i don´t know how to detect the alarm event. Please help.