# How to get alarm clock start ringing listener in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a lock screen application in Android work well and now I want to improve it a bit.
When the alarm of the device start ringing my lock screen application must be finish. Please tell me how can I catch the alarm start ringing listener?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question should point you in the right direction:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844657/how-to-detect-alarm-ringing-or-other-apps-using-speaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the alarm event. Upon receiving the relevant action you can stop you lock screen application.

Sample code will look like this,

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
          String action = intent.getAction();
          if (action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_ALERT") || 
              action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_SNOOZE") || 
              action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DISMISS") || 
              action.equals("com.android.deskclock.ALARM_DONE")) 
          {
              // Stop the screen lock application here...
          }
    }
};
```