# Ringing alaram detection in android phone

Tags: java, android

I need to detect if an alarm is ringing on the phone or not. I googled this, but the solutions are old. Any ideas on this? How can I detect if alarm is ringing or not?

[For example in this thread, there is no more ALARM_ALERT_ACTION, so I can not use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844657/how-to-detect-alarm-ringing-or-other-apps-using-speaker)

Comment: consider that there are a lot of 3rd-party alarm apps, not only system app. So basically an alarm app with alarm ringing is just any app in foreground, that is playing some sound.

Comment: Aha nice approach, thank you. I did not think this.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if there is app in foreground within my app?

Comment: unfortunately you can only detect if your own app is in foreground. But not any other app